# Safety of comparison operators with Integer objects in Java

Tags: java, reference, integer, comparison-operators

When is it safe to use comparison operators e.g. ==, >=, < in Java when using Integer objects and not primitive ints?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

I know == is dangerous with references, and you should use .equals instead, but what about the other operators? e.g.

```
int x = 7;
int y = 7;
Integer a = new Integer(7);
Integer b = new Integer(7);

System.out.println(x == y);
System.out.println(a == b);
System.out.println(a.equals(b));
System.out.println(a <= b);
```

prints

```
true
false // Why you should use .equals
true
true // Seemed dangerous but it worked?
```

Is it okay to use anything other than double equals (So >, <, >= and <= are safe?), or should I be using the .compareTo() method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is dangerous when the variable references `null`. The unboxing action will cause a `NullPointerException`.

The `<=` and `>=` operators are different than `==`. [They can only be applied to numerical primitive types (and values)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1), so reference equality is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

- If you know the values are not null, then `< > <= >=` are all OK, and they will unbox to `int`.
- You probably don't ever want to use `==` or `!=`, other than to check if an operand is null.  They'll do a reference comparison, not a value comparison - so you probably want to use the `equals` method instead.
- If there's a possibility that one of the values will be null, then `< > <= >=` are not safe - they can give a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Operators are okay with primatives.
Methods(eg. .equals() or .equalsIgnoreCase())
Are used on objects.

Comment: Nothing. With .equalsIgnoreCase() I was thinking in terms of String. Thanks for the catch.